# Can someone explain racket's store passing style?

Tags: lambda, filter, scheme, racket, store

I am working on assignment, we have to partition a list as per the predicate(even?). 
Example:
(filter-sps even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) '())

output:
(2 4 6 8 10)
(1 3 5 7 9)

I am not able to generate 2 separate list.

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways to do this. I wouldn't necessarily choose store-passing as the most straightforward, though.

I'm willing to bet that this is for a class, and that if we try to answer without understanding more about the class context, we won't be steering you in the right way. So: can you say a little bit more about the requirements of the problem?

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that store-passing-style is just that: a style. There's nothing about store-passing that's specific to Racket; you can do it in any language. It's simply a programming style where rather than performing mutation on data structures, you pass a representation of memory along as an argument to future function calls (and return it as well).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter twice:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

(define odd? (lambda (n)
                 (not (even? n)))) ; in case you don't have odd

(cons (filter-sps even? lst)
      (filter-sps odd? lst))
```

Iterating over the same list twice is wasteful if the lists are very long, but for your example it is negligible